# How does an Operating System become corrupted out of nowhere?

Tags: windows-vista, operating-systems

My mother's Dell XPS system has been running fine and dandy for the past two or three years now, and just yesterday I was called in for an emergency situation. Turns out her operating system was corrupted unintentionally and out of nowhere. I was able to salvage data and run a virus scan on the hard drive and nothing seemed out of the ordinary. `chkdsk` did nothing for the disk and it would start up but networking, start menu, and other basic functions **refused** to work and doing anything in Windows Explorer would lock up the machine entirely.

**How can an operating system become corrupt with no user malpractice and no signs of a virus?**

Comment: "Turns out her operating system was corrupted"... Define "corrupted". Provide evidence that bolsters this conclusion. There are other problems that can cause problems besides viruses. @LarsTech's answer regarding flaky hardware, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a sign that hardware is getting flaky.  A loose connection inside the computer that might be disconnecting with vibrations, or sodering joints on the motherboard.  Electricity spike, etc.

Comment: The problem is definitely with the hard drive and more specifically, the operating system. A different hard drive runs fine and I can pull all the files off of the drive when booted from a separate drive. Definitely not a hardware problem.

Comment: @esqew - You don't consider a hdd hardware?